# How codechef compiler works?

Tags: compiler-construction, c++14

> I want to know how the codechef compiler works. Actually not only codechef compiler how other competitive platforms compilers works on backend. Because the output which I used to get on my local compiler sometimes differ from the online compilers specifically on codechef.

For example on my local compiler when I am running the below code I am getting the correct output :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int val, N, Z, count = 0, evacuate = 0;
        vector<int> v;
        cin >> N >> Z;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cin >> val;
            v.push_back(val);
        }
        std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
        while (Z > 0)
        {
            int power = v.front();
            Z = Z - power;
            std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            v.pop_back();
            power = power / 2;
            if (power)
            {
                v.push_back(power);
                std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            }
            else if(power == 0 && Z > 0){
                evacuate = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (Z < 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (evacuate)
            cout << "Evacuate" << endl;
        else
            cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

while the same code when I am running on codechef compiler to solve [codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA03/submit/SAVKONO) I am getting unexpected output (only 0's)

[image: Screenshot for comparing both the output2]

Also, the code working on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/).

How CodeChef Compiler Working and How the outputs in both are differing ? May be the problem can be on code too but locally, I am getting the correct outputs for the inputs provided manually.

Comment: The compilers CodeChef uses can be found here: https://www.codechef.com/wiki/list-compilers

Comment: Oh then should I use the same compiler which codechef is using instead of visual studio or any other else ? Have you studied the complete issue before down voting the problem ?

Comment: Don't worry about using the same compiler. If you don't use any advanced language features, and if your code doesn't have UB, any up-to-date compiler should give you the same results.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat do note that gcc 6.3 is a bit old, and only have partial support for c++17. Things like `string_view`, `gcd`, or `to_chars` will not be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked, your code work just fine. The problem is that you didn't have anything for the input.

Check the "custom input", then enter "1 5 25 7 13 8 17 3", and you would see the result as expected.

### Edit:

[image]

To do that, you would first check the checkbox in the red circle, then a text box would show underneath, where you can type in your test case in the blue box.

Comment: I want to know what type of input I doesn't have. I have seen you have submitted the code successfully on codechef just now but with what changes.

Comment: @shivanshshrivastava I didn't change anything, it was exactly the code you have. Sorry if I have accidentally submit it, not sure if you can still work on it anymore. I only meant to check if it works.

Comment: Got it may be I should submit instead of run. I am not familiar with codechef compiler that's why asked in above issue about it.

Comment: @shivanshshrivastava Check my edit, that's how you would try your custom test cases. For practice it doesn't really matter, while it would still be nice if you can try different test cases first. But if you were going to do any contest, you would usually get points off if you have submitted any wrong answers.

Comment: The last thing why this custom input not enabled for me. I mean I am unable to click on that. How to use it ? Lol

Comment: @shivanshshrivastava That is weird. Probably browser thing. Or maybe you didn't go through user verification? I'm using Safari 14.0 here.